# BSOD - HDD Detected in BIOS but not in diskpart or by Win 10 install

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bsod, diskpart

As per the title - my neighbour has asked me to take a look at his laptop after a BSOD.

Windows 10 Home won't boot, only option is to boot from USB and do a complete reinstall of Windows.

However, when doing this I can't see the HDD in the list of drives to install on.
I downloaded the compatible storage driver and attempted to load this in but apparently, it is not compatible with the system (despite using the device serial number to ensure I got the correct driver from the manufacturer website (Acer).

When I try to run the setup.cmd file for the driver in a command prompt, it is simply trying to run an EXE which clearly won't work without a GUI (hence not usable from command prompt).

The HDD is detected in the BIOS in HDD1 (strange that it isn't in HDD0 since that is empty and there is only 1 drive in the laptop), but not in diskpart (I can only see the two USB devices I have plugged in).

Any suggestions other than to take a brick to it?

Answer (score 0):

The hard drive has failed. Trying to install Windows 10 on this drive will not work.  You said "when doing this I can't see the HDD in the list of drives to install on"

So you need to replace the drive.

If there is needed data on the old drive, remove it and contact a local recovery agency. That is the best approach for the old drive.

Get a new drive and begin the installation of Windows 10. Windows 10 will properly activate on the the new drive (otherwise same computer).

Good luck.

Comment: The laptop - so the neighbour tells me - is 14 months old. HDD shouldn't be failing after 14 months of light use.

Comment: A HDD can fail at any time. They can be new, middle aged, or old. That does not matter. Mean time to failure allows failure any time. If the drive was working, it would be recognized. I have a desktop with 2 drives (now large SSD). HDD 2 failed after a year (reccovered, replaced under warranty); replacement failed a year after that. HDD 1 never failed until I changed to SSD. Time to failure is not a good indicator at times.

Comment: Surely if the drive had failed it wouldn't be recognised in BIOS?

Comment: The drive could be recognized but still have damage preventing you from writing to it. That has happened before.

Comment: Well I guess we'll never know since I can't get the Western Digital Diagnostic Tool to run via cmd line (all the bat script does is run an exe in GUI mode). Any idea how to do so?

Comment: You can try starting with the WD Drive Test app on USB to see if that will work.

Comment: Do you have a link to said app? The ones I've looked at on the WD download site are all exe's that need a GUI in order to run. They cannot be run from cmd prompt.
I should also note I made a Ubuntu USB bootable drive, and this recognises the HDD.

Comment: Try this WD bootable USB app:  https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?p=2

Comment: Thanks...Not sure if you read the instructions on how to set that up, but it mentions at the end of creating the bootable USB, it should prompt you for a cmd prompt where you can run the exe. But that doesn't work - it doesn't give you a cmd prompt, it simply fails to run. I therefore booted from the bootable Windows USB drive, ran a shift + f10 during setup and then attempted to switch to the other USB drive with the diagnostic tool on, and run the program but it simply says it isn't compatible with that version of Windows.

Comment: It is a bootable USB and that does not need Windows. So I think this is confirming the drive is gone.  That is, the app is a drive test and if it cannot find the drive.

Comment: Did you download the DOS tool?  I think you would need that to be operating system independent.

Comment: I did. I tried the non dos one also (even though I didn't think it'd work). Neither would boot.

Comment: I think for sure now the hard drive in this machine is just dead. Time to replace it.

Comment: Ended up running SMART check on Ubuntu in the end, and that is flagging Read Error Rate value of 26373 - with an overall assessment of 'DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON'. So it was as you suspected. Thanks for your help.